# avoid cache miss related to 1:N relationship in entity-component-system

Tags: c++, caching, components, entity, c++14

How to avoid cache miss related to 1:N (`pirateship`-`cannon`) relationship in entity-component-system (ECS)?

For example, a `PirateShip` can have 1-100 `cannons`.  (1:N)
Each `cannon` can detach/attach freely to any `pirateship` at any time.

For some [reasons](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31888/in-an-entity-component-system-engine-how-do-i-deal-with-groups-of-dependent-ent), `PirateShip` and `Cannon` should be entity.

### Memory diagram

In around first time-steps, when `ship`/`cannon` are gradually created, the ECS memory looks very nice :-

[image]

**Image note:**

- Left = low address, right = high address
- Although there seems to be gaps, `ShipCom` and `CannonCom` are actually compact arrays.

It is really fast to access `cannon` information from `ship` and vice versa (pseudo code):-

```
Ptr<ShipCom> shipCom=....;
EntityPtr ship =  shipCom;  //implicitly conversion
Array<EntityPtr> cannons = getAllCannonFromShip(ship);
for(auto cannon: cannons){
    Ptr<CannonCom> cannonCom=cannon;
    //cannonCom-> .... 
}
```

### Problem

In later time-step, some `ship` / `cannon` are randomly created/destroyed.
As a result, `Entity`,`ShipCom` and `CannonCom` array has gap scattering around.
When I want to allocate them, I will get a random memory block from the pool.

```
EntityPtr ship = .....  (an old existing ship)
EntityPtr cannon = createNewEntity(); 
Ptr<CannonCom> cannonCom= createNew<CannonCom>(cannon);
attach_Pirate_Cannon(ship,cannon);    
//^ ship entity and cannon tend to have very different (far-away) address
```

Thus, the "really fast" code above become bottom-neck. (I profiled.)

[image]

**(Edit)**  I believe that the underlying cache miss also occur from different address between cannon inside the same ship.

For example (`@` is address of turret component),

- `ShipA` has `turret@01` to `turret@49`
- `ShipB` has `turret@50` to `turret@99`

In later timesteps, if `turret@99` is moved to `ShipA`, it will be :-

- `ShipA` has `turret@01` to `turret@49` + **`turret@99`** (mem jump)
- `ShipB` has `turret@50` to `turret@98`

[image]

### **Question**

What is a design pattern / C++ magic to reduce cache miss from frequently-used relation?

**More information:**

- In real case, there are a lot of 1:1 and 1:N relationship.  A certain relationship binds specifically to a certain type of component to a certain type of component.
- For example, `relation_Pirate_Cannon = (ShipCom:CannonCom)`, `relation_physic_graphic = (PhysicCom:GraphicCom)`
- Only some of the relation are "indirect" often.
- Current architecture has no limit on amount of `Entity`/`ShipCom`/`CannonCom`.
  I don't want to restrict it in the beginning of program.
- I prefer an improvement that **not** make game-logic coding harder.

The first solution that come to my mind is to enable relocation, but I believe it is the last resort approach.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to add another layer of indirection. It slows things down a bit, but it helps keeping compact your arrays and could help speeding up the whole thing. Profiling is the only way to know if it really helps.

That being said, how to do that?
[Here](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/03/09/sparse-sets/) is a brief introduction to sparse set and it's worth reading it before to proceed to better understand what I'm saying.

Instead of create relationships between items within the same array, use a second array to which to point.
Let's call the two arrays *reverse* and *direct*:

- *reverse* is accessed through the entity identifier (a number, thus just an index in the array). Each and every slot contains an index within the *direct* array.
- *direct* is accessed, well... directly and each slot contains the entity identifier (that is an index to access the *reverse* array) and the actual component.

Whenever you add a cannon, get its entity identifier and the first free slot in the *direct* array. Set `slot.entity` with your entity identifier and put in `reverse[entity]` the index of the slot. Whenever you drop something, copy the last element in the *direct* array to keep it compact and adjust the indexes so that relationships hold up.
The ship will store the indexes to the outer array (*reverse*), so that you are free to switch back and forth things within the inner array (*direct*).

What are advantages and disadvantages?
Well, whenever you access the cannons through the outer array, you have an extra jump because of the extra layer of indirection. Anyway, as long as you succeed in keeping low the number of accesses made this way and you visit the *direct* array in your systems, you have a compact array to iterate and the lowest number of cache misses.

Comment: Wow, thank, good link. I have already use sparse set, but I have never known its common name!  .... By the way, I believe there is another problem (I forgot to mention, sorry).  Address of all `cannons` of a certain ship are scattered around in memory.  It may cause cache miss while iterating.  I don't think sparse array can solve it because I need the content (not just id/int) of `cannons`.  (iterating will surely fast, but cache miss will occur when `cannonCom->`)  .... I have edited the question and add an image to depict it.

Answer (score 2):

How about sorting the entities to minimize cache misses ?

Everytime a cannon and/or ship is added/destroyed/moved sort the entities.

I am not sure if this is feasible in your ECS system;
it wouldn't be practical if you heavily depend on the entity indices, they would change everytime you sort.